# What is the Maximum number of shapes that can be produced by super formula?

Tags: geometry

I recently saw this new beautiful formula called the [Super formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superformula)

It is used by the game NO MANS SKY for procedure generation of their resources...( Or something related to games...)

But my doubt is is there a limit for the Maximum number of shapes that can be produced by this formula until the shapes becomes so similar that it is indistinguishable by a human but still have different parameters of the equation. So what is that maximum limit of distinguishable shapes that can be generated using this formula !

UPDATE 
Pls don't consider "indistinguishable by human" actually what I want is, a neural network to distinguish between two shapes.As this a mathematics site I didnt want to bring the term "Neural network" into the question..Anyway now it's there !

Comment: @Crostul but the link works fine for me ?? I just checked it

Comment: FYI, this has nothing to do with "functional-analysis"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classifying things as 'indistinguishable by a human' isn't very well defined. For example, I'm sure that formula that you've linked to can create objects with $n$-fold symmetry for arbitrary $n$. Now, depending on the scale at which the objects have been drawn, someone may or may not be able distinguish between the two. So depending on what exactly you mean by 'indistinguishable by a human', the answer to your question could potentially by infinite.

Comment: Actually I just want a neural network to distinguish between the two shapes . !

Comment: That depends heavily on what the network has been trained to do. Since the number of shapes made by the function is definitely infinite (even if you only look at qualitatively similar shapes with changing number of symmetries), and the space of predictions that can be made by the neural network is finite (based on parameters relevant to the particular implementation of the network, such as size of the network, inherent computational discreteness in computations etc) thus the number of shapes distinguishable would depend on the neural network parameters, rather than the 'super formula'.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help ! I think I am getting something !

Comment: Also, not asking for upvotes or anything but in general please upvote and/or accept answers before abandoning the thread like several other new users.

Comment: as I am a user I can't upvote ! Otherwise I would have